# Comment on migrated answer not linked to my newly created account

Tags: support, bug, comments, migration, user-accounts

I was one of the answerers to a question later migrated: [Why do so many books indent all paragraphs except the first one in each chapter?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/86141/)

My answer had received a comment while still in its original location, and I responded to that comment. Later he deleted his comment and added another, leaving mine without context.  I was going to delete it, but with the page in its new location, it doesn't seem possible.  The ⊗ symbol for deletion, which normally appears when you hover over one of your comments, is not showing up.

I did not have an account on the target site at the time of migration, but my comment was not linked to my account (as my answer was) even *after* creating an account on the site.

Comment: You answered your question in your question itself, so I'm not sure what you're expecting anyone to tell you.

Comment: If this is behaviour you actually observed you should probably remove the "Do" and "?" from your title and retag as [tag:bug]

Comment: @Cai It's working as designed, for exactly the reasons described in the question.

Comment: @Servy My wording was not the best. I have edited the question to show that I did not realize about the comment's non-linkage to me until I was half done writing the question. Even realizing that, I wondered if this was something commonly known, or perhaps it might be a very minor bug. So I was expecting people to say stuff like, *what's new?*, or *that's a bug*, or *that's intentional behavior*. 

Comment: @RichF I fail to see what the edit changes.  So you figured out the answer to your question halfway through writing it.  You still know the answer to your question...

Comment: @Servy I did not "figure out the answer", I "suspected a cause". You all have confirmed it.  Thank you.

Comment: @RichF are you saying the comment was still not linked to your account *after* you joined the site? (Which is how I read the Q) or only that you weren't able to delete *before* you joined?

Comment: @Catija I joined the Graphic Design SE several hours ago so that I could do some up-votes. The system gave me ownership of my answer, but not my comment to that answer. But I'm not unhappy. 

Comment: @Cai Right, still not linked after joining. Technically I don't know if I could have deleted it before joining (I didn't notice until after), but I highly doubt it.

Comment: Then that is IMO certainly a bug.

Comment: @Cai, I agree with you and Catija.  Thank you for the edits. At first I thought it an extremely minor bug, maybe not worth bothering with, particularly as it concerned me.  But thinking about it, I can imagine cases where the commenter might have very good reasons for wanting to delete one of his comments.

Comment: Even if they don't want to delete it, migrated comments *usually* line up with whoever made them if that user already has an account. They shouldn't get abandoned if that person joins after the migration.