# Upvoting your own comments is possible in site-migrated posts

Tags: bug, comments, migration, up-votes

I know this might be a trifle, but I wanted to mention this in case this is unexpected behaviour. I recently got [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/1723137/advice-in-how-to-properly-maintain-my-ups?noredirect=1#comment2661448_1723137) migrated from Server Fault to Super User. I didn't have a user created in Super User at the moment of the migration, so I created it afterwards.

Now, if I access this post, I can upvote my own old comment since it was done on another site. (Well, I have undone the upvote so I can't anymore, but you understand what I mean).

I guess SE does not recognize I am the same user.

Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: That only can happen with comments that were migrated before you make an account, the ones with a black, non-linked username.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comment on migrated answer not linked to my newly created account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291818/282094) and this ***should*** be the duplicate; based on the wording of the title: [What are the rules regarding comment migration?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178485/282094)